# Getting org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed. error for connecting to Heroku

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to connect a simple Java code with PostgreSQL database on Heroku. I have tried everything as needed, but I am getting the following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

I am not able to understand what is going wrong.

Following is the code I am using:

```java
String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://some-text.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/some-text?ssl=true&sslmode=require";
        String username = "some-text";
        String password = "some-text";

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed: " + e.toString() + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,username,password);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            String query = "select * from table";

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

            while(resultSet.next()){
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString("column")); 
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: You should include the whole stack trace in the question.

Comment: What version of the `org.postgresql:postgresql` JDBC driver are you using in your `pom.xml`?